# How to represent a set of numbers in sql query

Tags: mysql, select

I would like to know if it is possible to represent a set of numbers (IDs) using `<> 1, 2, 3, ...etc` in an sql query.  Here is my query at the moment:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dName
FROM department
    INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id_Dept = department.id_Dept
    INNER JOIN emp_proj ON employee.id_Emp = emp_proj.id_Emp
    INNER JOIN project ON project.id_proj = emp_proj.id_proj
WHERE project.id_Proj <> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
```

Comment: You mean like [NOT IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)?

Answer (score 0):

you may use [`NOT IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) for that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dName
FROM department
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id_Dept = department.id_Dept
INNER JOIN emp_proj ON employee.id_Emp = emp_proj.id_Emp
INNER JOIN project ON project.id_proj = emp_proj.id_proj AND project.id_Proj NOT IN {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'in' operator to solve above probelm..

Here is the sample code

```
select * from department where dept_id in (1,2,3);
```

Above query will result only record with where dept_id is 1, 2 or 3

Comment: Tnx for the reply and sorry!  I want the project.id_Proj does NOT equal 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6....

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE THIS

```
WHERE project.id_Proj <> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
```

TO THIS

```
WHERE project.id_Proj NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```